# Having issue with IE8 and IE7

Tags: html, css

i am trying to fix this but i m messed up. i m not spamming i really need help.

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>
    <link href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8 ]>
    <link href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

**IE7**

```
#site header #telephone {
    float: right:
    width: 600px;
}

#site header #telephone p {
    color: #fff;
}
```

and in **IE8**

```
header #telephone {
    float: right:
    width: 600px;
}
```

please preview this image for more information:

[image]

but nothing is happening when i try to open the site in IE7 or IE8.

Comment: Try taking your link tags out of the style tags, there is no need for them to be nested like that.

Comment: i don't understand. can you give me some example.. i m completly confused right now

Comment: `<!--[if IE 7 ]>
<style type="text/css">
    <link href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</style>
<![endif]-->` should be `<!--[if IE 7 ]>
    <link href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->`

Comment: kindly check the image i uploaded.. i am looking for this preview

Answer (score 1):

You must decide what you want, you use either a link tag to link in an external stylesheet, or you use the style tag. but not the link tag in the style tag.

Comment: please check the image i have uploaded.

Comment: The image alone will not help in solving the problem you must give the html and css for the page.

Comment: you have still the link link tag in the style tag. that will not work out. By the way you will need to fix the page also for IE9

Comment: please Ctrl + F5 to view recent results.